How should data be processed when returned from a Trino database?
I am attempting to fetch data from a Trino database. I send my initial query to the database and get a NextURI. In a while loop after that, I re-check the NextURI to get part of the data until the Trino connection finishes sending overall data.
The issue is that I get no data and endless NextURI's.
The code below reflects this process. Note that it starts off by getting an authentication token for Trino before continuing.

app.get("/getOpenskyData", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  console.log("Server | getHistoricalADSBData | Called");
  try {
    const startTimeEPOCHMS = Number(req.query.startTimeEPOCHMS);
    const endTimeEPOCHMS = Number(req.query.endTimeEPOCHMS);

    interface TokenPayload {
      access_token: string;
      exp: number;
    }

    // Get the token from OpenSky Network
    const result = await axios.post(
      "https://auth.opensky-network.org/auth/realms/opensky-network/protocol/openid-connect/token",
      new URLSearchParams({
        client_id: "trino-client",
        grant_type: "password",
        username: process.env.OPENSKY_USERNAME + "",
        password: process.env.OPENSKY_PASSWORD + ""
      }).toString(),
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
      }
    );

    const payload = result.data;
    const decoded: TokenPayload = jwtDecode(payload.access_token);

    // Ensure the token has an exp property
    if (!decoded.exp) {
      throw new Error("Token does not have an expiration time");
    }

    console.log("Server | getHistoricalADSBData | Got Token");

    const queryString = `SELECT * FROM minio.osky.state_vectors_data4 WHERE time BETWEEN ${startTimeEPOCHMS / 1000} AND ${endTimeEPOCHMS / 1000}`;

    // Execute the query on Trino
    const response = await axios.post(
      'https://trino.opensky-network.org/v1/statement',
      queryString,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${payload.access_token}`,
          'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
          'X-Trino-Buffer': 'true',
        },
      }
    );

    if (response && response.status === 200) {
      const body = response.data;
      const results: any[] = [];

      let nextUri = body.nextUri; // Initialize nextUri

      // Loop to handle pagination
      while (nextUri) {
        const fetchResponse = await axios.get(nextUri, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${payload.access_token}`,
          },
        });

        if (fetchResponse && fetchResponse.status === 200) {
          const fetchBody = fetchResponse.data;

          if (fetchBody.data && fetchBody.data.length > 0) {
            results.push(...fetchBody.columns); // Push data to results array
          }

          console.log(fetchBody.columns)

          nextUri = fetchBody.nextUri; // Update nextUri
          console.log(fetchBody.nextUri)
        } else {
          throw new Error('Unokay response whilst fetching data from OpenSky');
        }
      }

      console.log("Server | getHistoricalADSBData | Results:", results);
      res.status(200).json(results);
    } else {
      throw new Error('Unokay response whilst querying OpenSky');
    }

    console.log("Server | getHistoricalADSBData | Took " + (new Date().getTime() - startTime) + " ms");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Server | getHistoricalADSBData | Error of: ', (error as unknown as Error).message);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error while fetching historical ADSB.' });
  }
});

When I print the fetchResponse.columns field, I get the following results. Note that it is missing all of the required data, only including an array of a single ICAO24 value. I should be getting 100's of thousands of pieces of data for this request, as it is getting global ADSB data for one second.
[
  {
    name: 'time',
    type: 'integer',
    typeSignature: { rawType: 'integer', arguments: [] }
  },
  {
    name: 'icao24',
    type: 'varchar',
    typeSignature: { rawType: 'varchar', arguments: [Array] }
  },
  {
    name: 'lat',
    type: 'double',
    typeSignature: { rawType: 'double', arguments: [] }
  },
  {
    name: 'lon',
    type: 'double',
    typeSignature: { rawType: 'double', arguments: [] }
  },
  {
    name: 'velocity',
    type: 'double',
    typeSignature: { rawType: 'double', arguments: [] }
  },
  {
    name: 'heading',
    type: 'double',
    typeSignature: { rawType: 'double', arguments: [] }
  },
  {
    name: 'vertrate',
    type: 'double',
    typeSignature: { rawType: 'double', arguments: [] }
  },
  {
    name: 'callsign',
    type: 'varchar',
    typeSignature: { rawType: 'varchar', arguments: [Array] }
  },
  {
    name: 'onground',
    type: 'boolean',
    typeSignature: { rawType: 'boolean', arguments: [] }
  },
  {
    name: 'alert',
    type: 'boolean',
    typeSignature: { rawType: 'boolean', arguments: [] }
  },
  {
    name: 'spi',
    type: 'boolean',
    typeSignature: { rawType: 'boolean', arguments: [] }
  },
  {
    name: 'squawk',
    type: 'varchar',
    typeSignature: { rawType: 'varchar', arguments: [Array] }
  },
  {
    name: 'baroaltitude',
    type: 'double',
    typeSignature: { rawType: 'double', arguments: [] }
  },
  {
    name: 'geoaltitude',
    type: 'double',
    typeSignature: { rawType: 'double', arguments: [] }
  },
  {
    name: 'lastposupdate',
    type: 'double',
    typeSignature: { rawType: 'double', arguments: [] }
  },
  {
    name: 'lastcontact',
    type: 'double',
    typeSignature: { rawType: 'double', arguments: [] }
  },
  {
    name: 'serials',
    type: 'array(integer)',
    typeSignature: { rawType: 'array', arguments: [Array] }
  },
  {
    name: 'hour',
    type: 'integer',
    typeSignature: { rawType: 'integer', arguments: [] }
  }
]

The nextURI looks like the following:
https://trino.opensky-network.org/v1/statement/executing/20240619_210740_88003_jtdt5/y2e8bb6c86212fff8d50ab161a4300917292bc401/278

Note that I am 278 NextURIs in (so 278 seconds of processing) and am not getting data.
I can't find any documentation online on how Trino is supposed to format data when it sends it back, and I can't find any documentation on how to parse that data in JavaScript.
The query should not take 278 seconds to complete or return no data.
How am I supposed to process Trino data in Typescript correctly?
Edit: Here is the JSON.stringify of the response:
Fetched data:  {
  "id": "20240620_151923_60660_jtdt5",
  "infoUri": "https://trino.opensky-network.org/ui/query.html?20240620_151923_60660_jtdt5",
  "partialCancelUri": "https://trino.opensky-network.org/v1/statement/executing/partialCancel/20240620_151923_60660_jtdt5/0/ybcf17900e54b80c1b57f5be03beb9a24881ece39/17",
  "nextUri": "https://trino.opensky-network.org/v1/statement/executing/20240620_151923_60660_jtdt5/ybcf17900e54b80c1b57f5be03beb9a24881ece39/17",
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "time",
      "type": "integer",
      "typeSignature": {
        "rawType": "integer",
        "arguments": []
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "icao24",
      "type": "varchar",
      "typeSignature": {
        "rawType": "varchar",
        "arguments": [
          {
            "kind": "LONG",
            "value": 2147483647
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "lat",
      "type": "double",
      "typeSignature": {
        "rawType": "double",
        "arguments": []
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "lon",
      "type": "double",
      "typeSignature": {
        "rawType": "double",
        "arguments": []
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "velocity",
      "type": "double",
      "typeSignature": {
        "rawType": "double",
        "arguments": []
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "heading",
      "type": "double",
      "typeSignature": {
        "rawType": "double",
        "arguments": []
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "vertrate",
      "type": "double",
      "typeSignature": {
        "rawType": "double",
        "arguments": []
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "callsign",
      "type": "varchar",
      "typeSignature": {
        "rawType": "varchar",
        "arguments": [
          {
            "kind": "LONG",
            "value": 2147483647
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "onground",
      "type": "boolean",
      "typeSignature": {
        "rawType": "boolean",
        "arguments": []
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "alert",
      "type": "boolean",
      "typeSignature": {
        "rawType": "boolean",
        "arguments": []
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "spi",
      "type": "boolean",
      "typeSignature": {
        "rawType": "boolean",
        "arguments": []
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "squawk",
      "type": "varchar",
      "typeSignature": {
        "rawType": "varchar",
        "arguments": [
          {
            "kind": "LONG",
            "value": 2147483647
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "baroaltitude",
      "type": "double",
      "typeSignature": {
        "rawType": "double",
        "arguments": []
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "geoaltitude",
      "type": "double",
      "typeSignature": {
        "rawType": "double",
        "arguments": []
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "lastposupdate",
      "type": "double",
      "typeSignature": {
        "rawType": "double",
        "arguments": []
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "lastcontact",
      "type": "double",
      "typeSignature": {
        "rawType": "double",
        "arguments": []
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "serials",
      "type": "array(integer)",
      "typeSignature": {
        "rawType": "array",
        "arguments": [
          {
            "kind": "TYPE",
            "value": {
              "rawType": "integer",
              "arguments": []
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "hour",
      "type": "integer",
      "typeSignature": {
        "rawType": "integer",
        "arguments": []
      }
    }
  ],
  "stats": {
    "state": "RUNNING",
    "queued": false,
    "scheduled": true,
    "nodes": 3,
    "totalSplits": 1429,
    "queuedSplits": 71,
    "runningSplits": 69,
    "completedSplits": 1289,
    "cpuTimeMillis": 1953,
    "wallTimeMillis": 1314000,
    "queuedTimeMillis": 0,
    "elapsedTimeMillis": 19949,
    "processedRows": 0,
    "processedBytes": 0,
    "physicalInputBytes": 0,
    "peakMemoryBytes": 10560,
    "spilledBytes": 0,
    "rootStage": {
      "stageId": "0",
      "state": "RUNNING",
      "done": false,
      "nodes": 3,
      "totalSplits": 1429,
      "queuedSplits": 71,
      "runningSplits": 69,
      "completedSplits": 1289,
      "cpuTimeMillis": 1953,
      "wallTimeMillis": 1314000,
      "processedRows": 0,
      "processedBytes": 0,
      "physicalInputBytes": 0,
      "failedTasks": 0,
      "coordinatorOnly": false,
      "subStages": []
    },
    "progressPercentage": 90.20293911826452
  },
  "warnings": []
}

20 minutes of run time with no output rows.

